# What is wrong in this Python Sum Program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

```
a=input("Enter First Number ")
b=input("Enter second number ")
c=a+b
print("The Sum of two numbers are ",c)
```

"**Why This Program not printing Sum of tho number?s?**""

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the numbers to int. When you take an input, it is always a string. To cast a string to int, you can do `int(a)+int(b)`